# How would I route iPhone vocals into my DAW?

Tags: microphone, audio-interfaces, ableton-live, iphone, mobile

I have an iPhone 6s Plus with a cool vocal effect app. I also have a "Blue" condenser microphone, a Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 audio interface, and I'm using Ableton as my DAW.

What adapters and/or equipment would I need to use my iPhone apps on my vocals with my condenser mic, and route the audio to a track in Ableton, with live monitoring?

I guess I'd be using my iPhone as kind of an outboard effect/compressor.

Comment: Can your effect app record? Or you can use something like a pod-DI into your Scarlett

Answer (score 0):

You will need an *iOS compatible* digital audio interface to plug your mic in to the iPhone/iPad, and then connect the line-level output of that interface to the line-in jacks on the Scarlett interface to your computer (The cabling needed will varying depending on the iOS interface).

---

Alternatively, you can use a [TRRS-to-dual-TRS adapter](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/962633-REG/startech_muyhsmff_3_5mm_4_position_to.html?ap=y&c3api=1876%2C92051677562%2C%2C&gclid=Cj0KCQjwttbWBRDyARIsAN8zhbKiofBYWfHdrVEYD12_6MopzYCxMqsUd6ElS2sY9rfflr0Ph5SEnhMaAj_lEALw_wcB) to connect a line-out from the Scarlett the iPhone and then the line-out from the iPhone back to a line-in on the Scarlett to make a sort of outboard effects processor, but Your Mileage May Vary in regards to latency & quality.

---

A far better, but perhaps more expensive solution would be to find a comparable plug-in to run within your DAW.